# DNS entry to resolve external IP with internal address

Tags: windows, dns

I am not sure how to set this up and can find no information at all online.

I have a DNS server set up like:

```
+ Server-Name
    + Forward Lookup Zones
        - _msdcs.clientname.local
        - clientname.local
    + Reverse Lookup Zones
        - 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa
    + Trust Points
        <empty>
    + Conditional Forwarders 
        <empty>
```

What they want to do is resolve some.domain.com.au to a local address, say 192.168.0.10.

I don't know where to set this up.   If I add it to the forward lookup zones listed here, it appends the address to be some.domain.com.au.clientname.local

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out, I was trying to add the wrong kind of forward zone.

If you want say: service.clientname.com to resolve to 192.168.0.10

```
Right click on your Forward Lookup Zones folder.
Select New Zone...
Next
Primary Zone, Store in AD
Next
To all DNS Servers running on domain controllers in this domain
Next
Zone name:   clientname.com
Next
Allow only secure dynamic updates
Next
Finish
```

This will create the zone.   Now right-click on the zone you just created (clientname.com) and click

```
New Host(A or AAAA)...
Name: service   (this will correctly show service.clientname.com as the FQDN in the next field)
IP address: 192.168.0.10
Create Associated PTR record
Add Host
```

That's it. To test, ping service.clientname.com, you should now get 192.168.0.10